# iOS only CSS file?

Tags: css, ios, web-applications

Is there a way to include a CSS file that only works for iOS? Thanks.

It would be preferred if this is done browser side, although server side detection could be a viable option if it works well enough (server is python flask based)

Comment: server side is easier and better

Comment: Any idea how to do that via python flask?

Answer (score 3):

You can use CSS media queries:

http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/iphone4-ios4-detection-safari-viewport

Comment: yeah just compile iPad/iPhone/etc specific mq's into one

Comment: I read somewhere that now this should be the preferred method, instead of using JavaScript and querying for the userAgent. It is also the method that Apple describes in their videos: <link media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="iphone.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />.

Answer (score 2):

You could use some javascript

```
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i))     //Lines split for easy reading only
    || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) 
    || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))){
   //LINK TO YOUR STYLESHEET
}
```

Comment: ... or you could just write `.match(/iPhone|iPod|iPad/i)`. And I would drop the i after the last slash to avoid accidentally matching something else in the future.